# Google Sheets - Dependent Drop Down Script Query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

I am trying to create a dependent drop down in my sheet that in Col A will allow you to select a list of regions (e.g. Americas, Africa, Asia) etc and then in Col B will show a list of the countries in the region selected in Col A.

I have tried using an =indirect and =index/match formula but they do not work for the totality of my sheet, which is over 1000 rows.

There are 11 tabs in my workbook, however I only want to pull data from the 'countries' tab in to the 'Master Calls Sheet' tab for validation. All the other tabs are =filter cuts from the main sheet.

In the countries tab, I have listed the regions in Col A from Row 2, with the corresponding countries in Col B, so it reads like:

Africa . Ghana
Asia . Japan

and so on.

In my Master Calls tab, I have slicers etc at the top, so the data entry only starts from row 9.

I have attempted the script below, to no avail:

```
var mainWsName = "Master Calls Sheet";
var optionsWsName = "countries";
var firstLevelColumn = 1;
var secondLevelColumn = 2;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mainWsName");
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("optionsWsName");
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function myFunction() {

  function onEdit(e){
    var activeCell = e.range;
    var val = activeCell.getValue();
    var r = activeCell.getRow();
    var c = activeCell.getColumn();
    var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
    if(wsName == "mainWsName" && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 8){
       var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
       var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, 2);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell)
  }

  }}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build;

  cell.setDataValidation(rule)

}
```

Can anyone help?!?

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by using the following script which is composed of two functions: `createDropdown()` and the `onEditTrigger(e)`.

- **The global variables:**

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var master = ss.getSheetByName("Master Calls Sheet");
var countries = ss.getSheetByName("countries");
var options = countries.getRange(2, 1,countries.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
var continentsList = ['Americas','Africa','Asia'];
```

If you want to add other continents to the function, you should only change the `var continentsList` variable.

- **The** `createDropdown()` **function:**

```js
function createDropdown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(continentsList,true).build();
  ss.getRange('A9').setDataValidation(rangeRule);
}
```

The above function is used to create the dropdown with all the continents and it will be created on the `A9 cell` on the `Master Calls Sheet`.

- **The** `onEditTrigger(e)` **function:**

```js
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var countries = e.range.getSheet();
  var cellValue = e.range.getValue();

  var k =0;

  for (k=0; k<continentsList.length;k++) {

    if (cellValue == continentsList[k]) {
      countries.getRange("B9:B").clear();
      var j=0;
      for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) 
        if (options[i][0]== continentsList[k]) {
          j++;
          countries.getRange(j+8,2).setValue(options[i][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above function is an installable trigger which means that every time the value from the **dropdown** is changed, it will fire. It works by looping through the `continentsList` and it checks if the value from each iteration corresponds to the one selected from the dropdown. If the values correspond, then the countries from each continent are listed.

The values will appear on the `B column` starting from `B9` on the `Master Calls Sheet`.

The trigger should be set with the following properties:

[image]

Moreover, I suggest you check the following links since they might be of help in your future development:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [DataValidation Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/data-validation).

Comment: This is great - thanks so much! However, how can I have it so the list of countries that shows in col B the Master Calls Spreadsheet becomes a dropdown and can be edited differently in every row. So A9 = Africa which means B9 shows African countries, then A10 = Asia, so B10 shows asian countries?

Comment: Hello @challengedbycode, I'm glad that my solution worked for you! But why would you need a dropdown for the operation you mentioned above? Maybe I misunderstood your goal. Would you mind being more explicit? Cheers!

Comment: Of course not, and thank you so much for everything so far! In essence, I want to be able to record outreach to multiple countries on the same sheet. So have my selection be specific to the row so that I can have multiple rows of data - which then allows me to analyse where we are directing our outreach by country and continent etc. So it would be a dropdown in Col A, with a drop down in Col B (which shows only the countries on that continent selected) for every row in the sheet. Does that make sense? I am conscious that this might just be a stream of consciousness!

Comment: @challengedbycode, does this answer your question:
`for (k=0; k<continentsList.length;k++) {
    countries.getRange("B9").clear;
    if (cellValue == continentsList[k]) {
      for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) 
        if (options[i][0]== continentsList[k]) {
          countryList.push(options[i][1]);
      }
     
      var dataValidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(countryList, true).build();
      countries.getRange("B9").setDataValidation(dataValidation);
    }
  }
` of course, you have to declare `var countryList = [];` outside the for loop.

Comment: @challengedbycode and if you want to apply this to **multiple rows** (as I understood from your comment), you only have to include all the code above in a `for loop` which will loop through all the rows wanted - instead of `countries.getRange("B9")` you will have `countries.getRange("B"+m);`, assuming `m` is the variable used in your for loop. The same change should be applied to the `createDropdown()` function. Hope this solves your issue! Cheers :)